# Week Ending Date from Week no. - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How do I get the week ending date from week no. in GCP ?

```
SELECT 
  Session,
  Store_Num,
  Store_Name,
  EXTRACT (WEEK(Monday) from Route_Date) as Weekno,
  AVG(Planned_DPH) as Avg
FROM `TABLE` 
WHERE Route_Date  between current_date() - 60 and current_date()
  and Store_Num = 8881
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY Weekno
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first day of weekno with *PARSE_DATE* function and `%W` format string.

> %W - The week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number (00-53).

And by adding 6 more days to the first day of the week, you will get *the week ending date*.

Consider below sample query.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT DATE '2022-11-10' AS Route_Date
)
SELECT *,
       PARSE_DATE('%Y%W', Year || Weekno) AS startday_of_weekno,
       PARSE_DATE('%Y%W', Year || Weekno) + 6 AS lastday_of_weekno
  FROM (
    SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK(Monday) from Route_Date) as Weekno, -- 45
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Route_Date) AS Year,
      FROM sample_data
  );
```

**Query results**

[image]